# SIP extention created by FusionPBX can not login into softphone

Tags: postgresql, freeswitch, fusionpbx

I have a `FreeSWITCH` v1.6.13 on my Debian 8( From git) and it is OK.
After that i installed the last `FusionPBX` to manage my PBX telephony `FS`.
But it gives me error : 403 You must define a domain called x.x.x.x in your directory...
Both i installed by FusionPBX guid in their web site.
[FreeSWITCH](http://fusionpbx-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/additional_information/freeswitch.html) and [FusionPBX](https://www.fusionpbx.com/download.php).
Im going crazy cause about 4 days i Am working and not a good result yet.
I know Fusion store data in DB and i give him a Pgsql user name and password.( not the default one it suggest after ./install command) and also FS with --enable-core-pgsql-supprt in ./configureaiton with -C.
And i searched a lot, and all says as this link.
But when i go to sip status from FusionPBX, it says that my ip is correct, and also i did what they say but no success.
Just one time it worked! and i did not why it work.
And after it does not work and again says 403 you must ....
And after that i create an extention, i go to FS terminal and type user_exist 101 (user i created in fusionpbx)it return me false.
Can it be DB issue?
I do not know why just one time it worked and after i after that again gave me 403 error.
Cause i did changed a lot i could not understand what was the cause to work it.
Is it a bug?
What exactly i am doing wrong??
Really any help will appreciate.

EDIT 1 :
My softphone is android zoiper for test the created extention in fusion.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are using the "Extension" number as the username in zoiper.  Also go to the extension's settings page to see the current password for that extension.  I have used Zoiper on my android phone with FusionPBX.  So I know it will work.

Zoiper account settings will be:

- Account Name: Any name.
- Hostname: ip/hostname of FusionPBX
- Username: extension number
- Password: extension password.

One thing that confused me a lot when I first tried fusionpbx is the "Users" vs "Extensions".  From what I can tell "Users" are only for logging into the web UI of FusionPBX, for things like checking voicemail and managing other features.  The "Users" are not SIP users.